# Is it possible to customize DataWindow's buttons?

Tags: c#, wpf, catel

Given the `DataWindow` view with `DataWindowMode.OkCancelApply`, is there a way in [Catel](http://www.catelproject.com/) to customize styles of Ok, Cancel, Apply buttons? At least I need to define automation IDs for the buttons. I was trying getting `"_ButtonsWrapPanel"` in `OnApplyTemplate()` but `GetTemplateChild` returns null there. I believe there must be an easy way to do that in Catel without use of `AddCustomButton`.

Answer (score 0):

To customize the styles, you can modify the **DataWindowButtonStyle** style which is applied to all buttons.

There is no support to implement automation id's yet. This should be and easy fix, so please put it on the backlog so it will be implemented. We also do accept pull requests ;-)